# Find all users that logged in at a specific date and from a specific machine

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, grep

I would like to write a bash script, that takes two parameters as input (`day hostname`) and outputs the `username` of all users that logged in on the day of the **current month** and from the address of `hostname`.

I have written this code until now:

```
#!/bin/bash

#parameter correction checking
if [ ! $# -eq 2 ]
then echo "You have input the wrong number of parameters!"
fi

#Current month checking
CurrentMonth=`date | cut -d' ' -f2`
#This will contain the abbreviation of the current month: e.g "Mar"

#$2 -> IP/hostname; $1 -> day (of the current month)
last | grep '$2' | grep '$CurrentMonth $1' | cut -d' ' -f1
#here the two greps will get the lines that check out our requirements, and the cut will return only the username
```

What did I do wrong?
The code runs just fine if I replace the `CurrentMonth` variable with `Mar` and the `$2` with an actual `IP address`

Comment: Instead of writing `date | cut -d ' ' -f2` you could just write `date +%b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything between single quotes (`''`) will get treated as literal text and variables won't get expanded. Instead use double quotes (`""`) for strings that contain variables.

Note that you can always debug a bash script and get the expanded commands shown if you start it with `bash -x yourscript` or change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash -x`.

A working version of your script would look like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

#parameter correction checking
if [ ! $# -eq 2 ]
then echo "You have input the wrong number of parameters!"
fi

#Current month checking
CurrentMonth=`date | cut -d' ' -f2`
#This will contain the abbreviation of the current month: e.g "Mar"

#$2 -> IP/hostname; $1 -> day (of the current month)
last | grep "$2" | grep "$CurrentMonth $1" | cut -d' ' -f1
#here the two greps will get the lines that check out our requirements, and the cut will return only the username
```

---

**Notes:**

`last` by default prints an abbreviated username, you might want to add the `-w` flag to print the full name.

Also note that instead of `grep` you could use `last`s builtin  functions for filtering by time:

```
-s, --since time
           Display the state of logins since the specified time. This is useful, e.g., to easily determine who was logged in at a particular time. The option is often combined with --until.

-t, --until time
           Display the state of logins until the specified time.
```

```
TIME FORMATS
       The options that take the time argument understand the following formats:

       ┌────────────────────┬────────────────────────────────────────────┐
       │                    │                                            │
       │YYYYMMDDhhmmss      │                                            │
       ├────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────┤
       │                    │                                            │
       │YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss │                                            │
       ├────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────┤
       │                    │                                            │
       │YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm    │ (seconds will be set to 00)                │
       ├────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────┤
       │                    │                                            │
       │YYYY-MM-DD          │ (time will be set to 00:00:00)             │
       ├────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────┤
       │                    │                                            │
       │hh:mm:ss            │ (date will be set to today)                │
       ├────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────┤
       │                    │                                            │
       │hh:mm               │ (date will be set to today, seconds to 00) │
       ├────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────┤
       │                    │                                            │
       │now                 │                                            │
       ├────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────┤
       │                    │                                            │
       │yesterday           │ (time is set to 00:00:00)                  │
       ├────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────┤
       │                    │                                            │
       │today               │ (time is set to 00:00:00)                  │
       ├────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────┤
       │                    │                                            │
       │tomorrow            │ (time is set to 00:00:00)                  │
       ├────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────┤
       │                    │                                            │
       │+5min               │                                            │
       ├────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────┤
       │                    │                                            │
       │-5days              │                                            │
       └────────────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```